# Getting a unique_ptr for a class that inherits enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Usually I prefer returning `unique_ptr` from Factories.
Recently I came to the problem of returning a `unique_ptr` for a class that inherits `enable_shared_from_this`. Users of this class may accidentally cause a call to `shared_from_this()`, though it is not owned by any `shared_ptr`, which results with a `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception (or undefined behavior until C++17, which is usually implemented as an exception).

A simple version of the code:

```
class Foo: public enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    string name;
    Foo(const string& _name) : name(_name) {}
public:
    static unique_ptr<Foo> create(const string& name) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(name));
    }
    shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared() {return shared_from_this();}
    void doIt()const {cout << "Foo::doIt() <" << name << '>' << endl;}
    virtual ~Foo() {cout << "~Foo() <" << name << '>' << endl;}
};

int main() {
    // ok behavior
    auto pb1 = Foo::create("pb1");
    pb1->doIt();
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb2 = shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(pb1));
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb3 = pb2->get_shared();
    pb3->doIt();

    // bad behavior
    auto pb4 = Foo::create("pb4");
    pb4->doIt();
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb5 = pb4->get_shared(); // exception
    pb5->doIt();    
}
```

A possible solution is to change the factory method to return `shared_ptr` but this is not what I'm looking for, as in many cases there is actually no need for sharing and this will make things less efficient.

The question is how to achieve all of the following:

1. allow the factory to return `unique_ptr`
2. allow `unique_ptr` of this class to become shared
3. allow `shared_ptr` of this class to get shared copies (via `shared_from_this()`)
4. avoid failure when `unique_ptr` of this class tries to get shared from this (calling `get_shared` in above example)

Items 1 to 3 are fulfilled with the code above, **the problem is with item 4**.

Comment: I would be suspicious of a design which mixes shared and unique pointers to the same data structure.

Comment: Can you add an edit to explain your use case? I'm trying to imagine one and everything I can come up with tells me that you have a design problem (or the x-y problem).

Comment: Your `create` might better be `return std::make_unique<Foo>(name);`, no?

Comment: @kfsone the private constructor prevents the use of `std::make_unique<Foo>(name)`. There are some redesign options to allow it, but it was not the main issue here.

Comment: @SteveLorimer the use case is simple: there is a data structure (assume: Cat) which in some cases is sent to a processing chain that allow unique pointers (single threaded processing) where as there is another processing chain in which a different Cat (yet, a Cat) needs to be sent, without a clear ownership (a multi threaded processing in this case).

Comment: @AmirKirsh if you have a `unique_ptr` from which you need to create a `shared_ptr`, then the `unique_ptr` is not unique, and therefore you used the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @SteveLorimer well, when the Cat is born, it doesn't know whether it will need to be shared or not. The process the Cat traverse through may decide at a certain point that there is a need to share. It's obviously the right measure for a factory to always return `unique_ptr` (either a `unique_ptr<Cat>` or a `unique_ptr<Pet>` which actually may be a  `unique_ptr<Salamandra>`). Requiring the Cat, or the Pet factory, to know in advance whether there will be a need to share or not does not sound as a generic design rule for all cases, I can think of cases it fits and cases it doesn't.

Comment: @AmirKirsh without knowing your specific design it's difficult to say. What I can say is that it sounds like your design makes it difficult to get right - clients can call `shared_from_this` when they are in a `unique_ptr` setting. Scott Meyer's *Most Important Design Guideline* is [Make interfaces easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/IEEE_Software_JulAug_2004_revised.htm). As such, separating the single threaded/multi threaded part of the system from the `Pet`/`Cat`/`Salamandra` part would probably be a good idea - separation of concerns

Comment: @SteveLorimer That's exactly what I was looking for, making sure that clients may reach a point that sharing is required and it will work transparently without really caring if they are with a shared Pet or with a unique Pet (i.e. *making the interface easy to use correctly* etc.). Separating single threaded/multi threaded parts of the system doesn't mean that Pets do not tend to visit both parts, and in some cases start at one and end up at the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple static factory functions and conversion functions. To address your comments, I've added `get_shared` to support copying a shared pointer. This compiles and is available here: http://ideone.com/UqIi3k

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
    std::string name;
    Foo(const std::string& _name) : name(_name) {}
public:
    void doIt() const { std::cout << "Foo::doIt() <" << name << '>' << std::endl;}
    virtual ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo() <" << name << '>' << std::endl;}

    static std::unique_ptr<Foo> create_unique(const std::string & _name) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(_name));
    }
    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> create_shared(const std::string & _name) { 
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(_name));
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> to_shared(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &&ptr ) { 
         return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(ptr)); 
    }
    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared(const std::shared_ptr<Foo> &ptr) {
         return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(ptr));
    }
};

int main() {
    // ok behavior
    auto pb1 = Foo::create_unique("pb1");
    pb1->doIt();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pb2 = Foo::get_shared(std::move(pb1));
    //note the change below
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pb3 = Foo::get_shared(pb2);
    pb3->doIt();

    // also OK behavior
    auto pb4 = Foo::create_unique("pb4");
    pb4->doIt();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pb5 = Foo::to_shared(std::move(pb4)); // no exception now
    pb5->doIt();

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pb6 = Foo::create_shared("pb6");
    pb6->doIt();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pb7 = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(pb5);
    pb7->doIt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Amir I've addressed your concern and provided a working example of my solution.

Comment: I like this solution. It's better than mine as it doesn't require to inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` and it's simple.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the member function `get_shared` in the question is that it allows calls by both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` with a difficult to distinguish between the two, thus `unique_ptr` is allowed to call this method and fails.

Moving the `get_shared` to be a static method which gets the pointer to share from, allows the distinguishing between unique and share which fixes this problem:

```
class Foo: public enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    string name;
    Foo(const string& _name) : name(_name) {}
public:
    static unique_ptr<Foo> create(const string& name) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(name));
    }
    static shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared(unique_ptr<Foo>&& unique_p) {
        return shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(unique_p));
    }
    static shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared(const shared_ptr<Foo>& shared_p) {
        return shared_p->shared_from_this();
    }
    void doIt()const {cout << "Foo::doIt() <" << name << '>' << endl;}
    virtual ~Foo() {cout << "~Foo() <" << name << '>' << endl;}
};

int main() {
    // ok behavior - almost as before
    auto pb1 = Foo::create("pb1");
    pb1->doIt();
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb2 = shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(pb1));
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb3 = Foo::get_shared(pb2);
    pb3->doIt();

    // ok behavior!
    auto pb4 = Foo::create("pb4");
    pb4->doIt();
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb5 = Foo::get_shared(std::move(pb4));
    pb5->doIt();    
}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fd0d462ed486c44

Comment: `get_shared(const shared_ptr<Foo>& shared_p)` is mostly useless, as the usage of `shared_from_this()` is when we just have instance (pointer of reference), but not within its `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's the pitfall of minimal code example... assume that the method we wish to call (modeled as *get_shared* in this example) needs to perform several things, among them to get a new shared pointer of the caller (e.g. in order to send it to a process in another thread that may outlive this thread). We want to make this transparent to whether the caller had initially in hand a unique_ptr or shared_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

Deriving from `enable_shared_from_this` is a promise that your instances are owned by a (group of) `shared_ptr`. **Don't lie** about this, only ever create `shared_ptr<Foo>` and  *never* hand out `unique_ptr<Foo>`.

It's not worth the future pain when you have to disentangle the "safe" uses of `unique_ptr<Foo>` from the case where a `Foo &` deep in some logic that wants to call `shared_from_this` but *sometimes* is actually a `unique_ptr<Foo>`.

Answer (score 1):

> That's exactly what I was looking for, making sure that clients may reach a point that sharing is required and it will work transparently without really caring if they are with a shared Pet or with a unique Pet (i.e. making the interface easy to use correctly etc.).

It sounds like the x-y problem to me.

To "make sure that clients can share if required", turn this into a separate tool and put this in your toolset (**edit:** but it still feels like you have the x-y problem):

```
namespace tools
{

    /// @brief hides the details of sharing a unique pointer
    ///        behind a controlled point of access
    ///
    /// to make sure that clients can share if required, use this as a
    /// return type
    template<typename T>
    class pointer final
    {
    public:

        // @note: implicit on purpose (to enable construction on return,
        //        in the client code below)
        pointer(std::unique_ptr<T> value);

        // @note: implicit on purpose (to enable construction on return,
        //        in the client code below)
        pointer(std::shared_ptr<T> value);

        T* const operator->() const { return get(); }

        /// @note copy&swap
        pointer& operator=(pointer p)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(value1, p.value1);
            swap(value2, p.value2);
            return *this;
        }

        // example copy
        pointer(const pointer<T>& value)
        : value1{}, value2{ value.share() }
        {
        }

        // example move
        pointer(pointer<T>&& tmp)
        : value1{ std::move(tmp.value1) }, value2{ std::move(tmp.value2) }
        {
        }

        /// @note conceptually const, because it doesn't change the address
        ///       it points to
        ///
        /// @post internal implementation is shared
        std::shared_ptr<T> share() const
        {
            if(value2.get())
                return value2;

            value2.reset(value1.release());
                return value2;
        }

        T* const get() const
        {
             if(auto p = value1.get())
                 return p;
             return value2;
        }

    private:
        mutable std::unique_ptr<T> value1;
        mutable std::shared_ptr<T> value2;
    };
}
```

Your client code then becomes:

```
class Foo
{
    string name;
    Foo(const string& _name) : name(_name) {}
public:

    using pointer = tools::pointer<Foo>;

    static pointer make_unique(const string& name)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Foo>(name);
    }

    void doIt()const {cout << "Foo::doIt() <" << name << '>' << endl;}

    virtual ~Foo() {cout << "~Foo() <" << name << '>' << endl;}
};

int main() {
    // ok behavior
    auto pb1 = Foo::make_unique("pb1");
    pb1->doIt(); // call through unique pointer
    auto pb2 = pb1.share(); // get copy of shared pointer
    auto pb3 = pb1; // get copy of shared pointer

    auto pb4 = std::move(pb1); // move shared pointer
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. But, are you sure `shared_from_this` can be called from a static method (`static pointer make_shared()`)? can you post a link to the code?

Comment: It cannot; I have altered the code to avoid shared_from_this altogether. Now, all sharing is done at pointer level. You could add an `enum class pointer_type { shared, unique }` and pass it as an argument to `Foo::make_unique` (but then you would have to rename it to `make_pointer` or similar); Then, based on this argument, you could do `return shared_from_this(name);` and you would still inherit from enable_shared_from_this. It is better to make that inheritance private though.

Comment: You present a very neat approach! It is interesting to see a solution not using `enable_shared_from_this` (or a similar mechanics). But I'm still missing things in your solution, for example: operator -> for class pointer. Can you please add a link to the code? Thanks.

Comment: I added copy semantics and pointer access. I cannot make this into a full solution (I am in office and don't have much time).

Comment: It seems like an overly baroque solution to have a pseudo-smart pointer class to manage smart pointers. It's interesting, but it adds an extra layer of abstraction when the original design may be a problem instead.

Comment: @JonHarper, I know :( . It answers the question, but not the x-y problem. In practice, I would probably just use shared_ptr, but I cannot speak for the OP's concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you will have found, once an object is managed by a `shared_ptr`, there is no (safe) way to unshare it. This is by design, since once the lifetime of the object is shared, no one owner can guarantee that it will ever be the sole owner again (except during the execution of the deleter - I'll leave you to reason about whether that's useful to you).

However, the standard library does allow you to *specialise* any std class template provided it's specialised for a *user defined class*.

So what you can do is this:

```
namespace std {
  template<class Deleter>
  struct unique_ptr<Foo, Deleter> {
    static_assert(!std::is_same<Deleter, Deleter>::value, "sorry, not allowed");
    // or
    static_assert(!sizeof(Deleter), "sorry, not allowed");
    // (thanks to Jarod42 && md5i for cleaning up after me)
  };
}
```

And now no unique_ptr can ever own your object (which is clearly designed to be owned only by a shared_ptr).

This is enforced at compile time.

Comment: Indeed.  I usually use `static_assert(!sizeof(Deleter), ...);`.  The important bit is that it depends on one of the template arguments.

Comment: @Jarod42 ah yes, the one time I don't check my work in godbolt before shooting my mouth off... will fix. thank you.

Comment: @RichardHodges in this example we could have block the reasonable creation of `unique_ptr<Foo>` by changing the `create` method to return `shared_ptr<Foo>` instead of `unique_ptr<Foo>` (one can still do foolish things like `unique_ptr<Foo> pfoo = unique_ptr<Foo>(some_shared_pointer.get())` but I'm not looking for preventing such foolishness, fighting this level of foolishness is endless, better find the person who does it and release him) what I was looking for is avoiding a mistake that may happen, calling a method from a `unique_ptr` that in its turn tries to call `shared_from_this`.

Comment: @AmirKirsh so I would argue that preventing the creation of the unique_ptr in the first place is the way to go. The reason is that if a class is derived from `enable_shared_from_this`, it is necessarily unusable. There is no argument for creating it in the first place.

Comment: @RichardHodges I disagree. That's the discussion I'm having with @SteveLorimer above. Having the possibility of being shared doesn't mean being *always* shared. An argument saying that a type may be either unique or shared makes the constructor `shared_ptr(unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&&)` redundant.

Comment: @AmirKirsh the only reason to ever derive from `enable_shared_from_this` is that the class itself will call `shared_from_this`. If it does this while not being controlled by a `shared_ptr`, this is a logic error. There is no reasonable case for this possibility.

Comment: @RichardHodges I will rephrase your sentence to: the only reason to ever derive from `enable_shared_from_this` is that the class itself ***may*** call `shared_from_this`. I argue that you may start with a `unique_ptr` of this class, in some cases staying with unique till its death (the `unique_ptr` walked through the process and did not need to share) and in some cases may need to share (e.g. a need to send it to another thread). Again, I argue that this is not far away from the need to turn `unique_ptr` in some cases to `shared_ptr` through `shared_ptr(unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&&)` constructor.

Comment: @AmirKirsh the use case you describe is more properly handled with two classes. What you are doing is creating a trap for the user of your class, both when deriving from it and when manipulating a pointer to it. I am resolute. There is no reasonable case for the design you describe.

Comment: @RichardHodges we would probably agree to disagree... for me two classes sound like having two classes one for handling a pointer to an object and another one when we need an aggregate type. And then there is also the question why there is a `shared_ptr(unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&&)` constructor if `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` shall not be mixed...?

Comment: @AmirKirsh of course your code is your own. You may do as you wish. I hope I never have to maintain it. Best of luck.

Comment: @RichardHodges who knows? it's a small world :-) I see you ignore my question on why is there a need for `shared_ptr(unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&&)` constructor if `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` shall not be mixed and a type may be either unique or shared in all use cases.

Comment: @AmirKirsh it's because a class can be owned by a shared_ptr without being derived from enable_shared_from_this. In the case the assignment is legitimate.

Comment: Why does this work? Isn't is possible that `sizeof(Deleter) == 0` if for instance it is an empty struct? Or did I miss something

Comment: @ChrisBeck an empty struct has a size of at least 1. This is so that an array of them puts a hand one at a separate address. It's in the standard.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that. So when we make all these function objects with no members, technically they have size of one? Even if after the optimizer is done, they don't exist?

Comment: @ChrisBeck if nothing depends on their size or address, the optimiser can remove them entirely. No, there's no waste.

Comment: I see, that's an interesting subtlety. It makes sense though, I guess it's pretty important to be able to make arrays and do pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @ChrisBeck it also follows that the address of an object is a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread already, but I stumbled to ponder a question if its always quaranteed that `weak_from_this().expired()==true` or `weak_from_this().use_count() == 0` for an object not managed by `shared_ptr` - including `unique_ptr`. If yes, then simple answer to original question could be to realize non-throwing version of shared_from_this() via such checks for objects returned from factory.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your answer is probably more appropriate for a comment, because it involves an implicit question that the answer is contingent upon. It takes 50 rep to comment, so that option is not open to you now. It would be a better answer if you researched the `weak_from_this().expired()` issue and reported the findings. On old posts it often makes sense to try to evaluate if the answer you are proposing provides something additional over the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

May be we can template check of the calling variable ::

```
class Foo : public enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    string name;
    Foo(const string& _name) : name(_name) {}
public:
    static unique_ptr<Foo> create(const string& name) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(name));
    }
    template <typename T>
        shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared() { return shared_ptr<Foo>(); }
    template <>
    shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared<unique_ptr<Foo>>() { return shared_ptr<Foo>(); }

    template <>
    shared_ptr<Foo> get_shared<shared_ptr<Foo>>() { return shared_from_this(); }

    void doIt()const { cout << "Foo::doIt() <" << name << '>' << endl; }
    virtual ~Foo() { cout << "~Foo() <" << name << '>' << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    // ok behavior
    auto pb1 = Foo::create("pb1");
    pb1->doIt();
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb2{ std::move(pb1) };
    shared_ptr<Foo> pb3 = pb2->get_shared<decltype(pb2)>();
    pb3->doIt();

    // bad behavior
    auto pb4 = Foo::create("pb4");
    pb4->doIt();
        shared_ptr<Foo> pb5 = pb4->get_shared<decltype(pb4)>(); // exception
        if (pb5 != nullptr)
            pb5->doIt();

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if that is exactly what you want, but might solve the point 4 you have mentioned.

Comment: That's a nice solution, however requires the caller to make a more cumbersome call (with the `decltype`). I prefer my own answer which achieves the same just by turning the method to be a static method that gets the object to operate on as an argument.

Comment: Well, there is another problem with your solution: **it doesn't work**. I fixed some compilation errors to be able to run it, trying to call `pb5->doIt();` crashes (maybe this is why you had `if (pb5 != nullptr)`). Here is the code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79fe4af7fe5bbe84

Comment: In my IDE it works perfectly fine! Anyway it doesn't matter, the point is made. have a great day!