# Will move from unique to shared pointer also initialize enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

When I inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, but I create a unique_ptr, will the `weak_ptr` inside `std::enable_shared_from_this` also be initialized when I "move" to a `shared_ptr` by `std::move`, or by the move constructor?

For example what will happen in the below code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this< A >
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr< A > getA()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr< A > u(new A());
    // Aborts
    //std::cout << u->getA() << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr< A > s(std::move(u));
    // Will this work or abort too?
    std::cout << s << ", " << s->getA() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: std::move is basically a noop, it doesn't to anything. The move constructor is the only one that can initialize the object.

Comment: I've elaborated my question a bit. I mean when I create a shared_ptr  from a weak_ptr. Will it init the std::enable_shared_from_this base class?

Comment: @Eljay the question is if the `unique_ptr` is moved to a `shared_ptr`, will this move result into the that `weak_ptr` data being set.

Comment: Show your code example in the form of a [MCVE].

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher interesting info!

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing movement of the pointer with movement of the pointee, maybe? What are you moving, exactly? `enable_shared_from_this` does not have a move ctor and thus doesn't move shared state, but I'm not convinced that's relevant here. Depends on your [MCVE].

Comment: So you have a unique_ptr with this shared_from_this object (that's already a bug, no?) and you create a new shared_ptr out of it, which doesn't make sense because there is already a shared_pointer with shared_from_this. Creating another is wrong.

Comment: I've added some example code, does this show what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, better thank you

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38058060/560648?

Comment: Probably, yes...

Comment: Not convinced that the duplicate really answers the question

Comment: It answers different solutions with unique_ptr -> shared_ptr that seem to work (haven't had the time to look in details).

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, that is the right code for the question

Comment: Isn't the answer pretty obvious? Why shouldn't it work? What would be the point of `enable_shared_from_this` if it wouldn't work? Any construction of a `shared_ptr` that holds an object derived from `enable_shared_from_this` sets the weak pointer that implements the `shared_from_this` magic.

Comment: @Walter I wanted to figure out if I should inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this even though my factory will return a unique_ptr. In the ubique_ptr it's not initialized obviously. I thought it was a legitimate question. Now I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this all the `std::shared_ptr` constructors should initialise the internal weak reference so moving a `std::unique_ptr` into a `std::shared_ptr` should enable the use of `shared_from_this`.

You do have to be careful that nobody calls `shared_from_this` whilst the object is owned by `std::unique_ptr` as that is either undefined behaviour or will throw `std::bad_weak_ptr` depending on your c++ version.

Answer (score 4):

> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/1** In the constructor definitions below, enables `shared_from_this` with `p`, for a pointer `p` of type `Y*`, means that if `Y` has an unambiguous and accessible base class that is a specialization of `enable_shared_from_this` (23.11.2.5), then `remove_cv_t<Y>*` shall be implicitly convertible to `T*` and the constructor evaluates the statement:
>
> ```
> if (p != nullptr && p->weak_this.expired())
> p->weak_this = shared_ptr<remove_cv_t<Y>>(*this, const_cast<remove_cv_t<Y>*>(p));
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> template <class Y, class D> shared_ptr(unique_ptr<Y, D>&& r);
> ```
>
> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/29** *Effects:* ... equivalent to `shared_ptr(r.release(), r.get_deleter())`
>
> ---
>
> ```
> template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);
> ```
>
> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/10** *Effects:* Constructs a `shared_ptr` object that owns the object `p` and the deleter `d`. When `T` is not an array type, ... enable `shared_from_this` with `p`

So yes, `std::shared_ptr< A > s(std::move(u));` does initialize things appropriately to make `shared_from_this` work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Alan and Igor, the `std::weak_ptr<>` implementing the `shared_from_this()` magic is set appropriately whenever `std::shared_ptr<>` is constructed to hold an object publicly derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. So, yes you code will work.

However, the member method

```
std::shared_ptr<A> A::getA()
{
    return shared_from_this();
}
```

will envoke UB (prior to C++17) unless the object is actually managed by a `std::shared_ptr<>`. Unfortunately, prior to C++17, there is no way to tell from within the object (of type `A`) whether it is managed by a shared pointer, and you cannot easily prevent this UB.

Since you're actually using `std::unique_ptr<>` to manage your objects, I recommend therefore to not inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.